# Getting a few values out of dictionary with default different than None (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't quite like this: [Accessing python dict with multiple key lookup string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320335/accessing-python-dict-with-multiple-key-lookup-string)

So:

```
In [113]: d = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [114]: va, vb = map(d.get, ['a', 'b'])

In [115]: va, vb
Out[115]: (1, 2)
```

But:

```
In [116]: va, vb = map(d.get, ['a', 'X'])

In [117]: va, vb
Out[117]: (1, None)
```

What if one needs a default different than None?

I could use lambda:

```
In [118]: va, vb = map(lambda x: d.get(x) or 'MyDefault', ['a', 'c'])

In [119]: va, vb
Out[119]: (1, 'MyDefault')
```

But that's kind of convoluted and not very economic tradeoff for writing 2 d.get(key, 'MyDefault') calls.

Anything better (short of obvious solution of writing trivial utility function for that)? Esp. in Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: 'MyDefault', {'a':1, 'b':2})
>>> d['c']
'MyDefault'
>>> map(d.get, ['a', 'c'])
[1, None]
>>> map(d.__getitem__, ['a', 'c'])
[1, 'MyDefault']
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter would be:

```
In [40]: d = {'a':1, 'b':2}

In [41]: va, vb = [d.get(k, 'MyDefault') for k in ['a', 'X']]

In [42]: va, vb
Out[42]: (1, 'MyDefault')
```