# How to update multi-level dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
test_dict = {'path': '/home/user/user_name','device1': {'IP': '10.10.10.10','password': 'pwd1','username': 'user1','name':'USER_DEFINED'},'device2': {'IP': '11.11.11.11','password': 'pwd2','username': 'user2','name':'USER_DEFINED_TEST'}}
keys_to_be_updated = "path,device1/name,device2/name"
values_to_be_updated = "/home/user/user_name/ABCD,USER_TESTER1,USER_TESTER2"
k = 0
list_of_values = values_to_be_updated.split(",")
if keys_to_be_updated != "":
    for i in keys_to_be_updated.split(","):
        for j in i.split("/"):
            tmp = "['"+str(j)+"']"
        # test_dict[tmp] = list_of_values[k]
        # How to assign values to multi level dictionary here
        # test_dict['path'] = list_of_values[k]
        # test_dict['device1'][name'] = list_of_values[k]
        # test_dict['device2'][name'] = list_of_values[k]
        k = k+1
```

How do i update multi-level dictionary in the above code ? At the end, i should get the dictionary with the new values updated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320335/accessing-python-dict-with-multiple-key-lookup-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `zip` after splitting the strings on comma  and then iterating on the keys after splitting on a slash:

```
for k, v in zip(keys_to_be_updated.split(','), values_to_be_updated.split(',')):
    d = test_dict
    keys = k.split('/')
    if len(keys) == 1:
        d[k] = v
    else:
        for i in keys[:-1]:
            d = d[i]
        d[keys[-1]] = v

print(test_dict)
# {'device2': {'username': 'user2', 'IP': '11.11.11.11', 'password': 'pwd2', 'name': 'USER_TESTER2'}, 'path': '/home/user/user_name/ABCD', 'device1': {'username': 'user1', 'IP': '10.10.10.10', 'password': 'pwd1', 'name': 'USER_TESTER1'}}
```

Comment: Thank u. It works perfectly as i needed. If key-value pair already exists, it overwrites.Otherwise it adds. What's the significance of 'zip' here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Moses' solution, except that it avoids doing the `if` in the loop.

```
from pprint import pprint

test_dict = {
    'path': '/home/user/user_name',
    'device1': {
        'IP': '10.10.10.10',
        'password': 'pwd1',
        'username': 'user1',
        'name':'USER_DEFINED'
    },
    'device2': {
        'IP': '11.11.11.11',
        'password': 'pwd2',
        'username': 'user2',
        'name':'USER_DEFINED_TEST'
        }
}

keys_to_be_updated = "path,device1/name,device2/name"
values_to_be_updated = "/home/user/user_name/ABCD,USER_TESTER1,USER_TESTER2"

data = keys_to_be_updated.split(','), values_to_be_updated.split(',')
for key, val in zip(*data):
    keychain = key.split('/')
    d = test_dict
    for k in keychain[:-1]:
        d = d[k]
    d[keychain[-1]] = val

pprint(test_dict)
```

**output**

```
{'device1': {'IP': '10.10.10.10',
             'name': 'USER_TESTER1',
             'password': 'pwd1',
             'username': 'user1'},
 'device2': {'IP': '11.11.11.11',
             'name': 'USER_TESTER2',
             'password': 'pwd2',
             'username': 'user2'},
 'path': '/home/user/user_name/ABCD'}
```

---

Here's a minor variation. We use `map` to do the comma-splitting step.

```
data = keys_to_be_updated, values_to_be_updated
for key, val in zip(*map(lambda u: u.split(','), data)):
    keychain = key.split('/')
    d = test_dict
    for k in keychain[:-1]:
        d = d[k]
    d[keychain[-1]] = val
```